# Using the apply or plyr when the return has a variable number of columns

Tags: r, plyr, apply

I'm wondering if there is a way to directly return a data frame from an `apply` or `plyr` call when the return from the function can have a variable number of columns (but will always have the same number of rows). For example:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = c("a","b", "c"))

my_fun <- function(x){
  if(is.numeric(unlist(x))){
    return(x)
  } else {
    return(cbind(x, x))
  }
}
```

The closest I've been able to get is by returning a list and converting it into a data frame:

```
library(plyr)
data.frame(alply(df, 2, my_fun))
##   A X2.B X2.B.1
## 1 1    a      a
## 2 2    b      b
## 3 3    c      c
```

It feels like there should be a way to do this without the extra conversion, is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `lapply()` a lot in this way, when you want to apply a function to several columns of a data frame. In base R, you can treat a data frame as a list, where each column is one element. If you use lapply() as usual it will return a list, which isn't what we want.

```
> lapply(df, my_fun)
$A
[1] 1 2 3

$B
     x x
[1,] 1 1
[2,] 2 2
[3,] 3 3
```

But if you assign the result to `df[]` it will signal to R that you want a subset of your original data frame (the full subset, which isn't a subset at all), thus preserving the data frame object type.

```
> df[] <- lapply(df, my_fun)
> df
  A B.x B.x
1 1   1   1
2 2   2   2
3 3   3   3
```